# How can I generate a single-file component with Angular's CLI?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

Let's suppose I need an Angular component which is so small that the best option for it would be a *single-file* component.

An error alert like the one below would be such an example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-errors',
  template: `<div class="alert-error">{{ errorMessage }}</div>`,
  styles: [
    `
    .alert-error {
      color: #721c24;
      background-color: #f8d7da;
      border-color: #f5c6cb;
      padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 0.25rem;
    }
    `,
  ],
})
export class ErrorsComponent {}
```

In order to make this component I have run `ng g c error-alert` in the CLI. Then I deleted all the files  generated by the CLI *except* `error-alert.ts`. Then I moved it outside of the *error-alert* directory (which I deleted).

#### The problem

I wished (and still do) there was a simpler and faster way to make a *single-file component*.

#### Questions

1. Is there a CLI command that would generate a single-file component?
2. If there isn't such a command, can we configure the CLI so that there is? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try adding some flags like so.

```
> ng generate component <component-name> --inlineTemplate=true --inlineStyle=true --skip-tests=true
```

This should stop the generation of css/html/spec file.

There is now also an option on more modern versions to do the same with standalone components.

```
--standalone
```

More options surrounding generating with specific goals can be found [in the angular CLI docs](https://angular.io/cli/generate#component-command).

You can also edit `schematics` object in your `angular.json` to set these flags to default when generating a component if you wanted to take this further.

```
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular": {
      "component": {
        "inlineTemplate": true
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: `standalone` unfortunately only means that it should not be a part of a module. It has nothing to do with how many files are generated.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new configuration to make `ng g component` generate only one ts and spec file.

In `angular.json`, add the following under "sematics" property:

```json
"schematics": {
  "@schematics/angular:component": {
    "inlineStyle": true,
    "inlineTemplate": true
   }
}
```

Also, you can use extensions to get CSS and HTML syntax highlighting. Here is one - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template

More in depth tutorial to creating single file component in Angular - https://muhimasri.com/blogs/how-to-create-a-single-file-component-in-angular/